# Displaying documents SP2013 SharePoint Hosted App Model

Tags: datatables, sharepoint-2013

So what are the cool kids using for displaying documents inside a SharePoint Hosted App Model? Right now, I'm doing rest calls and attempting to display the data using jquery datatables plugin. It works but isn't exactly usable, not to mention that I have to make additional async calls to get Author names, etc.

Should I dump REST and use CSOM and format the data accordingly? Build the hyperlink to the item, format date, build Author name.

Seems like I'm re-inventing the wheel here and want to make sure that I'm not overlooking something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, what about DataTables is not usable? If the data is in the JSON return, it can obtain the data directly. Sorry, I know this doesn't help you, but I'm trying to make DataTables better, so I'm interested to know what use cases it is failing to deliver on at the moment!

Comment: it really isn't a critique of Datatables. The usability is hindered if the data isn't useful. For example, no one wants to look at an authorid or a date in some weird format. I've come to the conclusion that the rest call is going to populate a javascript array. Once in the array, I'll make additional calls to fill in the gaps and format what is left over. Once the data is pristine, then I'll bind it to datatables.

Comment: You can just have DataTables not show that data by using the mData option - you don't need to have it show every bit of data in the JSON response!